# How to open movie gallery in swift

Tags: ios, swift, media-player, uiimagepickercontroller, video-gallery

i'm trying to open the movie's gallery on ipad, but I have this error and i don't know why.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Source type must be UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera'
```

This is my code:

```
func GaleriaVideo() {
   if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum) {
        println("Galeria Video")

        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie]
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

        imagePicker.showsCameraControls = false

        imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = .Custom
        self.presentViewController(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Similar code works for me to photo gallery, but i don't know why this not works.

Can you tell me what's wrong in my code, or what i have to search to do this? i'm trying this for few days ago and i'm feel lost.

Thanks you,

EDIT:

This is my Photo gallery and it works:

```
    func GaleriaImagen() {

    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum){
        println("Galeria Imagen")

        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

        imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = .Custom
            self.presentViewController(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController!) {

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: NSDictionary!) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: I found this:  imagePicker.mediaTypes = [String(kUTTypeMovie)] in another post, maybe it helps

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
func GaleriaVideo() {
   if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum) {
        println("Galeria Video")

        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie]
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

        imagePicker.showsCameraControls = false

        imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = .Custom
        self.presentViewController(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a small addition. When using with Swift kUTTypeMovie, which works, import this library: import MobileCoreServices

Answer (score 0):

Add: `UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`

```
func gallery() {
  if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary) {
    var img = UIImagePickerController()
    img.delegate = self
    img.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    //img.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage]; //whatever u want type
    img.allowsEditing = false
    self.presentViewController(img, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: NSDictionary!) {
  self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)    
}
```

Comment: already had added UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate. 
i have "var img = UIImagePickerController()" in a global scope into the class

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Aju answer this will work for swift 2

```
func GaleriaVideo() {
  if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum){
    print("Galeria Video")
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
    self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
  self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
  //Here you can manipulate the adquired video
}
```

Comment: Just a small addition. When using with Swift kUTTypeMovie, which works, import this library: import MobileCoreServices

Answer (score 0):

Swift3/4 :

```
func GaleriaImagen() {        
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.savedPhotosAlbum){
            print("Galeria Imagen")
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.savedPhotosAlbum
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
            imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
            self.present(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```